# Need to resequence a column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with a column used to order the rows.  I need to be able to re-sequence that column, while honoring the (sometimes out of order) existing data.

Here's my starting data:

```
+-------+-------+---------+
| id    | mySeq | myText  |
+-------+-------+---------+
|  1    | 1     | First   |
|  2    | 99    | -->Last |
|  3    | 3     | Third   |
|  4    | 4     | Fourth  |
+-------+-------+---------+
```

Here's what I want to end up with:

```
+-------+-------+---------+
| id    | mySeq | myText  |
+-------+-------+---------+
|  1    | 10    | First   |
|  2    | 40    | -->Last |
|  3    | 20    | Third   |
|  4    | 30    | Fourth  |
+-------+-------+---------+
```

I already have a sequencer in the database that looks like this:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE [dbo].[CountBy10] AS [int]
START WITH 10
INCREMENT BY 10
```

Here is my most recent attempt (this resequences but doesn't respect the order of the original 'mySeq' column, it is processing the rows in the order of the 'id' column.

```
ALTER SEQUENCE CountBy10  
RESTART WITH 10;

UPDATE TestTable  
SET mySeq = NEXT VALUE FOR CountBy10
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT TOP(9999) id FROM TestTable ORDER BY mySeq);
```

Unfortunately, SQL Server doesn't allow you to include an `ORDER BY` clause when doing an `UPDATE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an updatable CTE:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*, row_number() over (order by myseq) as seqnum
      from testtable t
     )
update toudpate
    set myseq = seqnum * 10;
```

You do not need a sequence for this task.